# How to test nested collections with FluentAssertions

Tags: c#, collections, tdd, fluent-assertions

I have the following spec

```
BidirectionalGraph Fixture = new BidirectionalGraph();

public void VerticesShouldBeAbleToAssociateMultipleEdges()
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;
    int c = 2;

    Fixture.AddEdge(a, b);
    Fixture.AddEdge(b, c);
    Fixture.AddEdge(c, a);

    Fixture.EdgesFrom(a).Should().BeEquivalentTo
        ( new []{a, b} 
        , new []{a, c});
}
```

where EdgesFrom is defined so

```
public IEnumerable<int[]> EdgesFrom(int vertex)
```

however my test fails with

```
Result Message: Expected collection 

    {{0, 1}, {0, 2}} to be equivalent to 
    {{0, 1}, {0, 2}}.
```

Which doesn't quite makes sense to me as they are obviously equivalent.
Does `FluentAssertions` just not work when comparing collections
of collections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because collection.Should().BeEquivalentTo() uses the default Equals() implementation of your type to make sure each item in the first collection appears somewhere in the 2nd collection. What you really need is new [equivalency feature](http://www.dennisdoomen.net/2012/09/asserting-object-graph-equivalence.html) that I introduced in Fluent Assertions 2.0. Unfortunately I only recently became aware of confusing syntax (collection.Should().BeEquivalentTo() versus ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo()).

Comment: Naively I would assume that Should().BeEquivalentTo() would do nested structural equality testing. How about Should().BeEquivalentTo(depth:-1) for infinite depth and let depth take a default value of ``1`` to keep backward compatibility.

Comment: Makes sense. Internally, Should().BeEquivalentTo() should use the same structural equivalence API that ShouldBeEquivalentTo() offers.